# Read n bytes in a char array and return it as a double

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, byte, type-conversion

I'm trying to read and 3D image, and to do so, I use a library.
This library tells me the type of data (int, float, double, etc...) and returns me a void pointer to the data. I store it as a char*.

I'm creating a method, that takes as parameter x,y,z, and based on the datatype, I calculate the offset from the void pointer to the requested x,y,z value.

However, I now need to go to 'offset' position and read n bytes (based on datatype) and return the value as double (no matter the original type), but I'm not sure what is the best way to proceed.

I originally thought about casting the char* pointer to an int*, float*, double*, etc... (based on the datatype) and then read the value buffer[offset].
But as this is a method that will often be called, I'm not sure casting it every time will be efficient.

Thank you.

**Edit:** Here is a snippet, but it's not exactly the real one, as I have multiple classes, etc...

```
class DataReader{
public:
  DataReader(const char* filename);
  ~DataReader();

  double GetValue(int x, int y, int z);

protected:
  MyImage im_;
  char* data_;
};

DataReader::DataReader(const char* filename)
{
   this->im_ = read_image(filename);
   this->data_ = (char*)im->data; // (return a void*)
}

DataReader::~DataReader()
{
}

double DataReader::GetValue(int x, int y, int z)
{
  int databytes = this->im_->bytes_per_voxel;
  int offset = z*100*100 + y*100 + x;

  double value = 0;
  // TODO: Get data from this->data_ at location 'offset'

  return value;
}
```

Comment: A library gives you a `void*` through its public API? I wouldn't call that a C++ library - nor a good thing. You sure, you are coding C++ and not C?

Comment: casting is super efficient, can you share code snippet ?

Comment: If you are only casting the pointer then the cost will be virtually 0

Comment: The library is not recent (2010) and it started to be coded in 2002, so it's probably mostly C, but this is the best library I could find to handle the file format I need.

Comment: Reading 4 bytes, interpreting them as a 4-byte variable, and converting it to an 8-byte variable, is *very different* from reading 8 bytes and interpreting them as an 8-byte variable. Could you give us an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: use `memcpy` to copy from the `char *` to the `&double`.  Casting may run into alignment problems and breaks strict anti-aliasing.

Comment: Ok, so as an example, let's say I have an image of integers. Each value is coded on 4 bytes. Let's say the value at x=0, y=0, z=0 is 10. I want to be able to return 10 as a double (10.0) when the parameters of the GetValue are x=0, y=0, and z=0.

Comment: If I memcpy 4 bytes into a double, am I gonna keep the same value ? Will the copy happen on the first 4 bytes or the 4 last ? Also, is the memcpy gonna be efficient, as I will make lots of calls to this function ?

Comment: Isn't doing a `memcpy` between two unrelated types the same as doing a `reinterpret_cast` which is really dangerous?

Comment: It's the only legal way to do it anything else using pointers (or arrays) breaks the language rules.

Comment: "Accessing an object using an expression of a type other than the type with which it was created is undefined behavior in many cases, see reinterpret_cast for the list of exceptions and examples."  source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Strict_aliasing  Workaround http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy

Comment: But he knows which type it is. "This library tells me the type of data (int, float, double, etc...)"

Comment: What is an aliasing violation ? And if I have something like that, will it work: int n = 4; double v = 0; memcpy(&v, &n, sizeof(n)); with n = 4 bytes, v = 8 bytes. Will v = 4.0 ?

Comment: @whiteShadow Off-topic, but why do you insist on using `this->` in your code?  It clutters up things and is not necessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is how I've been taught to write. This is to avoid confusion about what belongs to the class and what is not.

Comment: I guess you have stock in a keyboard company.  Writing `this->` each and every time you mention a member variable has to be tiring.

Comment: Have you tried with your own solution (paragraph #4) and measure the performance? Are they acceptable?

Comment: It's like semi-colons, we get used to it :)

Comment: @Ceros not yet, I'm trying the memcpy method, but I get weird results.

Comment: I tried something like that: int n = 4; double v = 0; memcpy(&v, &n, sizeof(n)); with n = 4 bytes, v = 8 bytes, but it gives me weird values (like 5.75e-315, when I except a value of 3000). I guess it's because it depends where the bytes are copied in the double value.

Comment: @whiteShadow `I tried something like that: int n = 4; double v = 0;`  No way is that `memcpy` going to work.  You're assuming that an int's pattern of bytes is equivalent to a `double's` pattern of bytes.   Heck, you can't even guarantee that writing all zero's to a double will produce a `0.0`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok. So I probably misunderstood what you meant with the memcpy.

Comment: @Ceros I just did something like that: `int offset = (z*100*100 + y*100 + x); float* vals = (float*)this->data_; return vals[offset];` and it worked. So I guess I will have to do it for all datatypes.

Comment: @whiteShadow I didn't suggest the memcpy, just letting you know it isn't going to really work.  Let's assume that a double is 8 bytes, and the int is (for the sake of argument) also 8 bytes.  Let's say that the int is `0`.  Doing a `memcpy(&d, &n, sizeof(n))` would seem to produce a double that is equal to 0.0.  Nope, not guaranteed.  So the memcpy-ing of an integer type to a double is a no-go.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OK thank you. I misinterpreted what you said :)

Comment: @whiteShadow You should always use C++-style cast rather than the C-style cast. i.e. static_cast, dynamic_cast vs (int).

Comment: @Ceros I used a reinterpret_cast to do it. I cannot use dynamic or static because I'm converting a pointer, not data itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write and read the memory using the same data type.  So if your image is stored as ints, use int* to write to your data structure and use int* to read from your data structure.  Then at the last moment, cast the *data* to double (as opposed to casting the pointers).

Comment: This is what the OP tought first in his 4th paragraph.

Comment: I'm not sure to know what you mean. For me, I created a class that handle the image file, and I don't want the user to have to worry about the type of data in it or the format. So my class always return double (because this is the maximum precision, so if the image is in double, I won't lose any precision), but if it's a int, I will also return it as a double. I started doing something with a templated class, but too messy to handle, because I only know the datatype at runtime.

Comment: I was going to suggest templates for you.  If you have many data types to support, that is the way to go.  When I refer to the data structure, I mean the underlying image, which it looks like is stored on disk.  If the data type is int, put ints into it (intPtr[offset]=intValue) and take ints out of it(intValue=intPtr[offset]).  After you take ints out of the data structure or file, then cast them to double (double dValue= static_cast<double>(intValue));  You obviously don't care about efficiency yet, so this should work great.

Answer (score 0):

The following should accomplish what you need, although it can probably be optimized. If you're worried about performance and making calls to this often, I would consider preloading the data and recasting it all at once as an array, if it isn't too big to fit into memory. FYI, what you're doing seems strange, off the top of my head I don't see what you'd stand to gain from casting stored data values from lesser to greater precision.

```
double DataReader::GetValue(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int databytes = this->im_->bytes_per_voxel;
    int offset = (z*100*100 + y*100 + x)*databytes;//offset is now in bytes


    double value = 0;
    float rawValue;//We assume the values are stored as 4 byte floats. This will change for your particular problem. 

    memcpy(&rawValue, buffer[offset], databytes);
    value = rawValue;//Using implicit conversion, there may be a better way to do this.
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing it because I don't want the user to have to handle multiple data types. So my GetValue will always return a double, no matter the real datatype of the image. I choosed double because this is the maximum precision my data can have, so if they are double, I won't lose the precision. It will be useless if data are integers, but users won't have to handle it.

Comment: Would this do the same? 
`int* ptr = static_cast<int*>(buffer[offset]); 
value = static_cast<double>(*ptr);`

Comment: Very inefficient for image processing to use type double.  If you iterate over every pixel in a large image and for every pixel you have a function call and use type double, that is going to be horribly inefficient.

Comment: Ceros, I don't know if it matters, but I always cast pointers with reinterpret_cast

Comment: reinterpret_cast gives you 0 validation. You must have really good reason to use this.

Comment: @KyleSweet the images I get are in float mostly, but they can also be in double, so I don't really have a choice here. Although, I don't cast the whole image to double, it's just the returned value that I might need to be in double.

Comment: whiteShadow - If your images are stored as "float", it is clear that you do not care about speed performance.  Go with your original plan, which is what I tried to reiterate with my answer.  Please upvote and accept my answer, I'm trying to earn points.  Thanks!

Comment: Ceros - reinterpret_cast is awesome.  It guarantees that not a single bit will change as a result of the cast.  That's exactly what you want when casting pointers.  And it's so efficient that it can be implemented in literally zero cpu cycles.

Comment: @Ceros I wasn't sure, but looks like static cast does perform implicit conversion. So, OP, what's missing from the two answers currently submitted?

Comment: I'm just testing different things with static_cast, but it seems the only one that works properly is to reinterpret_cast the data pointer, and access it as an array and return the value as double.